# How to get top global public posts with most number of likes from facebook using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get top global public posts from facebook with most number of likes using fql, is there anyway to do it?

I am able to get the posts for a specific page and actor.

> SELECT message, likes.count, attachment FROM stream WHERE
>   source_id='SOURCE_ID' AND actor_id= 'ACTOR_ID'

but is there anyway like using queries like `max(likes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: **No**

- FQL is deprecated
- Public Post Search is deprecated
- Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and you cannot apply (at least not right now)

Links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

Comment: I need to find out the most popular content on fb I think I need to check the trends API under Public Content Solutions program do some R&D there. Thanks for the answer though.